# App ASP.NET Core with Crystal Quartz scheduler doesn't work with remote scheduler

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, quartz.net

I have got a scheduler in .net core console app, and I want plug in Crystal Quartz Panel in asp net Core app.

.net core console scheduler: Quartz 3.0.7
asp .net Core app Quartz 3.0.7, CrystalQuartz.AspNetCore 6.8.1

When I run app asp net core, program is terminated with message Process is terminating due to StackOverflowException.

this is some of my Quartz .net Core consol app

```
    "quartz.threadPool.type": "Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz",
    "quartz.threadPool.threadCount": "5",
    "quartz.threadPool.threadPriority": "Normal",

    "quartz.scheduler.exporter.type": 
    "Quartz.Simpl.RemotingSchedulerExporter, Quartz",
    "quartz.scheduler.exporter.channelType": "tcp",
    "quartz.scheduler.exporter.bindName": "QuartzScheduler",
    "quartz.scheduler.exporter.port": 666
```

This is my middleware in aspnet core

```
 app.UseCrystalQuartz(new RemoteSchedulerProvider()
            {
                SchedulerHost = "tcp://localhost:666/QuartzScheduler",
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/migration-guide.html says you can only use remote in a full framework version.